# How do I animate an entire gridview in android?

Tags: android, animation, gridview, sliding

I've got a grid view that fills the entire screen, and I want to animate the entire grid view sliding down a bit and an edittext sliding in from the top.

I placed the gridview in it's own relativelayout and animated that.

I created animations for both translations and they work, when I fire the animation the gridview slides down and the edittext slides down to become visible.

I have setFillAfter(true) on both animations.

However, two problems:

1) After the gridview slides down, the 'click positions' haven't moved, so the gridview responds to clicks from where the gridview items were before the animation.

2) If you scroll down the gridview to the bottom, it 'pops' and is back in it's original full screen position.

How can I fix these?

Comment: It looks like I have this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077549/moving-android-view-click-boundaries-after-animation need to use LayoutParams, will try and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Moving Android View click boundaries after animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077549/moving-android-view-click-boundaries-after-animation) - I needed to set the layout params again once the animation is complete. So in OnAnimationEnd, I set a margin equaling to the movement from the animation.